# Using NSUserDefaults to store unique order ID

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm developing a Point of Sale-kind-of-app, which runs on iOS and stores orders and payments in MySQL. I designed the order-table so that there is a client ID and a ClientOrderID which is a combined unique index, preventing duplicate sales.

The iPad gets its Client ID the first time it connects to the server and validates. This means no two iPads will ever get the same Client ID. If they reconnect they get a new one which is from a an auto-increment value of a column in another table designed for this.

Now, the client must of course also have a ClientOrderID to deliver to the server, so that the unique index becomes useful. What I did here is create a static method that looks like:

```
+(int)getNewOrderOrSaleID {

int orderid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"orderid"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:orderid+1 forKey:@"orderid"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

return orderid;
}
```

My questions is now this: Is this a reliable method, or does NSUserDefaults tend to mess things up?

And this is probably a bit far out, but doing this every time someone makes an order from the iPad, would that cause wear on the internal storage over time? This question is close to rhetorical, as I do realize how small the data amount is.

As it's only possible to make one order at a time, this method will never run two times at once.

Comment: Define 'mess things up'. Does it matter if the app is deleted and reinstalled? What about if the user restores from a backup?

Comment: Deletion is not a problem, as deleting the app will require that you validate the app again, giving you a new client ID and resetting the OrderID to 1.

Restore is a good point. I didn't think of that. But this is not developed for AppStore, I could just make it a policy to reinstall the app or re-validate the client after a potential restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are overwriting the same thing, you won't have new records in the user defaults, the existing one will change. And if you want to persist only some small information (like this `int`) the user defaults is a good place to do it. However, as Wain mentioned in the comment, the counter will be reset when you reinstall the app.

Comment: Resetting the counter doesn't matter, as you will get a new client ID then also and you can start from 1 again without giving duplicates.

Comment: Then you can use `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Okay. And I know it overwrites - I was referring to the actual write process on the storage being in the same place again and again. But I guess this is completely irrelevant in these modern days.